# Forum attachment real path, anyone knows?

Tags: ee2, image, forum, attachment

im trying to do something with Exif infos but using the {attach_image_url} isnt the right path, because ExpressionEngine generates something else than actual file name and location to it.

So, what i need, and hope to find out, is that what is the variable that could parse out the real url for the image attached.

Anyone, ideas?

**UPDATE:**

Im trying to get exif data out with this:

```
    <?php
$image_file = '{path:image_url}';
$image_type='';

$tab=str_repeat('&nbsp;',12);
if(file_exists($image_file)){
$details=exif_read_data($image_file);
foreach($details as $key=>$val){
echo $key.' = '.$val.'<br/>';
if(is_array($val)){
foreach($val as $key2=>$val2){
echo "<span style=\"margin-left:30px;\">".$key2.' = '.$val2.'</span><br/>'; 
}
}
}
}else{
echo 'File does not exists'; 
}

?>
```

But it doesnt find the image attached. I would be glad if someone could provide a way to get the real path to actual image attached, cos I cant find any kind of documentation of it anywhere. thanks.

Comment: Have you tested forum images in regular templates yet in regards to your other post? Did that work?

Answer (score 1):

If it's for the forum module then you'll probably need `{path:image_url}`. Give that a try.

Comment: {path:image_url} gives only the theme template path out when using it in forums that runs via regular templates. So im pretty sure that if someone can figure out how to pull out the actual image attachment file-url, then this awesome add-on will work smoothly in forums also. I have been testing this all day now and cant figure out other solution?  {attach_image_url} gives yout this: http://www.example.net/index.php?ACT=33&amp;fid=10&amp;aid=111663_NmtACUwAX0AGynl6lxFI&amp;board_id=1   in source code. But WHEN you right-click the image attached and open it into another window, the URL becomes

Comment: like this: `http://www.example.net/index.php?ACT=33&fid=10&aid=111663_NmtACUwAX0AGynl6lxFI&board_id=1` so there is big difference, and therefore using the {attach_image_url} can not be used.

Comment: I did try to use those urls that Forum gives, but in source code (as figured) add-on dont find actual file, because its trying to understand URL (here is the sourcecode info): `<!-- The file "http://www.example.com/index.php?ACT=33&fid=121&aid=111670_fWtMeGLuVM5ct06SuWfd&board_id=1" could not be found or was not in jpeg format -->`